# Pause and continue data capture through sensor when interrupts occur such as phone call

Tags: android

I am making an app in which I capture data through a sensor and render it on the rendering screen. The functionality is not complete. But before that I need to handle various interruptions such as incoming call or notifications.

So that at the time when user is capturing data from the sensor the data capture pauses if there is any interruption and then continues after interrupt is finished. I need to handle basically all the interruptions that can occur.

Answer (score 0):

override onResume() and onPause() on your Activity or Fragment

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html